# Getting Instance Of Service in Configure Services (Not by services.BuildServiceProvider())

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am implementing a custom ticket store and storing auth tokens in the database rather than cookies.

As part of this, I have created a CustomTicketStore and injecting like this

```
services.AddSingleton<ITicketStore, CustomTicketStore>();
```

Down further in the Startup.cs, I need to access the instance of this CustomTicketStore

When I am adding the cookie

```
.AddCookie("Cookies", o =>
            {
                // TODO: Have to fix this (not use BuildServiceProvider)
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var ticketStoreService = sp.GetService<ITicketStore>();
                o.SessionStore = ticketStoreService;
```

But then I get this warning from Microsoft
[image]

This is an alternate but ugly

```
//o.SessionStore = new CustomTicketStore(new AuthRepository(() => 
                //    new OracleConnection(connection_details);
```

Is there another way I can use the injected service?

Comment: A -1 without comment, that's brilliant

Comment: Can [this blog](https://makolyte.com/asp0000-calling-buildserviceprovider-from-application-code-results-in-an-additional-copy-of-singleton-services-being-created/) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling the service inside the configure service method, and this method could only inject the IServiceCollection and you want to set something store inside AddCookie method.

So there is no other way to get the registered service inside the Action  .